# How did Voldemort discover that Harry had the Philosopher's Stone in his pocket?

Tags: harry-potter

It is possible that Voldemort already knew about *The Mirror of Erised* and told Quirrell to bring Harry in front of mirror based on logic. But, how did he find out that Harry was lying, and more importantly, that the Philosopher's Stone was in his pocket?

Comment: Because he's a powerful wizard and he can sense Harry's thoughts.

Comment: @Richard He was weak and could barely talk.

Comment: Also, not sure if he could do magic in that form other than possessing other's bodies which should be result of previously done Horcrux magic.

Comment: "Hey is that the philosopher's stone in your pocket or are you just happy to see me?"

Comment: "But what has it got in its pocketses, eh?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all matters about Legilimency. Voldemort was highly skilled in the art of Legilimency.

Here is a quote of Harry Potter Wiki:

> "Voldemort has used Legilimency extensively, both wandlessly and
>   nonverbally, to enter the minds of those he wished to interrogate."

The quote can be found [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Legilimency), under History, third paragraph, first line.

This shows that Voldemort knew what he was doing because of his extensive knowledge, and this quote shows his skill:

> "You flatter me," said Dumbledore calmly. "**Voldemort had powers I
>   will never have**."

Voldemort was a very intelligent wizard.

To get to your question, here is another quote found on the Harry Potter Wiki:

> "If a target is not skilled in Occlumency, **a Legilimens will be able
>   to detect if the person is lying**, **as well as delve into their
>   thoughts**, emotions, and memories."

The quote can be found [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Legilimency), under Methods, first paragraph, second line.

Harry was not even aware of Occlumency and Legilimency, so obviously he would be "bad" at it. This was evidently shown during, and after the fifth book, during, and after his lessons with Snape. **Voldemort could have detected, through Quirrell that Harry was lying**, and furthermore **"delved into his thoughts", and saw that has was thinking about the stone in his pocket**.

This is purely speculation.

Comment: My only question about this answer is: Is there any evidence that Legimancy can be done without the target knowing?

Comment: @Zibboz, Harry doesn't realise Snape reads his mind several times over the series :-)

Comment: Could be like Crucio, Harry was eventually able to not feel its effects by Voldemort in 1998. Maybe Voldemort saw some of his thoughts, but Harry blocked them out unknowingly, because of his anger at him; like uncontrollable magic.

Comment: While it's clear that Voldemort can tell using Legilimency, we don't know if he ***did*** use it in this chapter.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Voldemort Trying to cover your tracks, eh?

Comment: I agree with @Voldemort. In the Philosopher's Stone book,Voldemort is still really weak. Legilimens requires a high focus on the targets mind and is shown to be really exhausting,especiallly for the target. Harry shows no signs of exhaustion and I highly .doubt that Voldemort was able to perform this spell in such a "weak" (host) body. He also seems to not have such a strong connection to Harry before he takes his blood to obtain a body in GoF AND he leatns about his special connection to Harrys mind in Ootp years later. I think he just guessed.

Answer (score 3):

Harry had been clutching his pocket from the moment the stone appeared in it.  All Voldemort had to do was look at him and read his body language well enough, and apparently he did.

It should also be noted that Voldemort had a mental link to Harry's mind, which may have let him more easily read what Harry was thinking.

Comment: 1. Harry never cltched his pocket. He only felt something heavy in his pocket. 2. As for mental connection based memory transfer, this is good one, but do you have canon citation? Harry used to saw nightmares based on Voldemort's memory, but was it true in reverse?

Comment: @infinity war, Dumbledore avoided Harry Potter because he is afraid Voldermort will see him. Also when Dumbledore took the fall of the Dumbledore's Army club. Harry felt Voldermort's anguish towards Dumbledore when he looked at Dumbledore.

Comment: @Bernard that was a lot later, when Voldemort became aware of the connection. Dumbledore was not avoiding Harry in the first year, however